# Unable to convert or understand dates in strange format

Tags: python, datetime, time, strptime

I am converting a bunch of dates in a database into unixtimestamp in python. There are entries in the database written like:

```
Thu Jun 16 10%3A08%3
Wed Jun 8 09%3A39%3A
```

Can any one tell me what this means? And possibly how to convert this over into a unixtimestamp?

Any other dates such as: `Thu Oct 14 15:11:47` I just use strptime to convert it over, but the ones above are giving me issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'%3A'` bits are the url encoded representation of a colon `:`. You can use the [`urllib.unquote()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) function to decode those strings:

```
>>> urllib.unquote("Wed Jun 8 09%3A39%3A")
'Wed Jun 8 09:39:'
```

...but it looks like the dates got stored in a fixed-length field and the seconds have been truncated.

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`urllib.unquote`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) here:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote('Thu Jun 16 10%3A08%3')
'Thu Jun 16 10:08%3'
>>> urllib.unquote('Wed Jun 8 09%3A39%3A')
'Wed Jun 8 09:39:'
```